# Couldn't start client ESLint message in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

Recently I run into problem with ESlint extension in VS code. When I launch VS code and open up a js file, it popup message "Couldn't start client ESlint". It used to work fine. I tried to re-install eslint, VS code but it didn't help. Here are the versions I used.

VS code: 1.44.0 (user setup)

eslint: v6.8.0

ESLint Extension for VS code: 2.1.2

Comment: im not sure why this happens but i did find this which doesnt really give an explanation: https://dev.to/takuyakikuchi99/vscode-couldn-t-start-client-eslint-3bp

Comment: The link instructs you to remove 'eslint.trace.server: null' from the settings.json file. Even though it does not give an explanation it did solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dig a little bit more to get more details.
A good place to start would be to run the eslint show output command in VSCode. That should be a good starting point.

[screenshot of ESLint: Show Output Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r2oo.png)

The bottom line is that you need to follow the conventional installation path:

- add eslint extension in vscode.
- install eslint locally or globally via npm,
- run eslint init in your project path and select proper configurations.
- restart vscode just to make sure the settings are active.

again, the eslint output console should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turns out I had the `eslint.runtime` and `eslint.nodePath` settings set to the specified node path on my system, but they were prefixed like this:

`~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node`

Using `$HOME` instead of `~` didn't solve it either.

I ended up having to specify an absolute path:

`/home/<myusername>/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node`